# $HK$ is a subgroup where $H \subseteq N_G(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $H, K$ be subgroups of $G$.  Let $HK=\{hk: h \in H, k \in K\}$ and $H \subseteq N_G(K)$.

I'm a bit stuck on something.  It makes me a bit nervous that $H \subseteq N_G(K)$.  Does this mean that $HK=KH$ or for every $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ there is an $h' \in H$ such that $hk=kh'$.  I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563559/h-k-leq-g-with-h-leq-n-gk-properties-of-the-subgroup-hk), but in this question it has that $K$ is a subgroup.

Comment: $K$ is also a subgroup here. I don't see the difference between the questions.

Comment: It's a subset.  $H$ is a subset of the normalizer of $K$

Comment: It is a subgroup of $G$ and therefore also of any subgroup of $G$ it is contained in.

Comment: Do you know that $\;A,B\le G\;,\;\;A\lhd G\implies AB\le G\;$ ?

Comment: Sorry.  $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.  But, $H$ is also a subset of $N_G(K)$.  This is why I'm worried.

Comment: @DonAntonio No I don't know that fact.

Comment: Try to prove it then, @jdla, usign that $\;AB\le G\iff AB=BA\;$ . Normality of one of the factors helps a lot here.

Comment: AS Tobias told you, @jdla, a subgroup of $\;G\;$ is **also** a subgroup of *any* other subgroup that contains it, not merely a subset.

Comment: I think I phrased my question poorly.

Comment: What I'm worried about is that subset assumption.  For completeness I just included the rest of the question I'm working on.

Comment: I don't see how that subset assumption makes you worry. What about it makes you worry, given the things already mentioned here?

Comment: If you continue calling it "subset assumption" then either you didn't understand what's been told to you in the comments, or else you don't quite accept it or else you're not careful enough to write.

Comment: And precisely that assumption is what makes so straightforward that $\;HK\le G\;$ ...!

Answer (score 0):

$N_G(K)$ is the normalizer in $G$ of the subgroup $K$.  It's the set of all $g$ such that $gKg^{-1} = K$.

So since $H \subset N_G(K)$, all of $h \in H$ also commute with $K$ like the $g$ above. So $hK = Kh, \ \forall h \in H$  Take the union over $H$ to show that $HK = KH$.

QED

Answer (score 0):

Does not

$N_G(K) = \{g \in G \mid g^{-1} K g = K \}? \tag{1}$

Indeed it does; now for $h_1, h_2 \in H$ and $k_1, k_2 \in K$ we wish to establish that

$h_1k_1h_2k_2 \in HK, \tag{2}$

so we follow (1) and note that since

$h_2 \in H \subseteq N_G(K) \tag{3}$

we have

$h_2^{-1}Kh_2 = K, \tag{4}$

which readily implies

$h_2^{-1}k_1h_2 \in K, \tag{5}$

whence there exists $k_3 \in K$ such that

$h_2^{-1}k_1h_2 = k_3, \tag{6}$

or

$k_1h_2 = h_2k_3, \tag{7}$

whence

$h_1k_1h_2k_2 = h_1h_2k_3k_2 \in HK, \tag{8}$

which shows that $HK$ is multiplicatively closed.  If $H$ and $K$ are finite, so that $HK$ is also finite, we are done, since a finite multiplicatively closed subset of any group is a subgroup.  In the event that $HK$ is infinite, we need to establish that the identity $e \in G$ is in $HK$ and that $(hk)^{-1} \in HK$ for $h \in H, \, k \in K$.  Well, $e \in HK$ is virually self-evident, since $H, \, K$ being subgroups implies $e \in H, \, K$; if $hk \in HK$, then $(hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1}$; but again, since

$h^{-1} \in H \subseteq N_G(K), \tag{9}$

we find that

$hk^{-1}h^{-1} = (h^{-1})^{-1}k^{-1}h^{-1} \in K, \tag{10}$

and thus we must have $k_4 \in K$ with

$hk^{-1}h^{-1} = k_4, \tag{11}$

whence

$k^{-1}h^{-1} = h^{-1}k_4 \in HK, \tag{12}$

showing that indeed $(hk)^{-1} \in HK$.  This completes the proof that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ under the given hypothesis.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux***